# Samba passwords expiring in x days - how do we fix them to not expire

Tags: password, samba, ldap

We use OpenLDAP and Samba v3.  Recently some Samba-defined users (no accounts on the shared linux server) started being listed in logwatch as having their passwords come up to "will expire"...I changed the names.

```
   password for user unicorn will expire in 7 days: 1 Time(s)
   password for user xMacAlphbet will expire in 7 days: 1 Time(s)
   password for user klbomb will expire in 4 days: 1 Time(s)
```

None of thee users have a linux user account.  How can I fix these?

Comment: are you using `pwdPolicy` schema in LDAP?

Answer (score 5):

First look for

```
pdbedit -u $username -v
```

This should display every property about this particular user.

```
pdbedit -P "maximum password age" -C -1
```

This then should disable the max password age for all accounts.

Taken from:
http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/pdbedit8.html

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use also `pdbedit -u $username -c "[X]"` which will add "Password does not expire" flag to specified user (and will set `Password must change` attribute to some point in distant future).